# SQLAlchemy with PostgreSQL Unicode issue

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, unicode, orm

I need to create and connect to a database PostgreSQL 9.2 using SQLAlchemy. So far, I am able to create the full db in UTF-8, but I have trouble putting non-ASCII characters into it. This is how I connect to the db:

> url = URL(drivername=s'postgresql', username='uname', password='pwd', host='localhost', port='5432', database='postgres')
>   self.engine = create_engine(url)

Then I create the new db, switch to it, and start to populate it: everything is ok. I get this:

> entercursor.execute(statement, parameters)
>   sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (DataError) invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xec2d43
>   
> 'INSERT INTO province (codice_regione, codice, tc_provincia_id, nome, sigla) VALUES (%(codice_regione)s, %(codice)s, %(tc_provincia_id)s, %(nome)s, %(sigla)s) RETURNING province.id' {'nome': 'Forl\xec-Cesena', 'codice': 40, 'codice_regione': 8, 'tc_provincia_id': 34, 'sigla': 'FC'}

I have the same code for the same db on MySQL 5, it works perfectly. I don't know what is wrong. I registered the extension of postgres for unicode, but this does not work. I am puzzled, I need the help of somebody more experienced.

Answer (score 3):

The `0xec2d43` sequence corresponds in iso-8859-1 to the 3 characters `ì-C` which would be part of the name 'Forlì-Cesena', according to the error log.

So the program is sending valid iso-8559-1, not UTF-8, while the server expects UTF-8.

The simplest way to fix the problem is to inform the server about the actual encoding, by issuing at the client side this SQL statement:

```
SET client_encoding=latin1;
```

Either that or convert the data to UTF-8 before passing it to the database, which is @Tometzky's answer.

Comment: thanks for your answers, I added the  encoding='latin1' on create_engine and when I pass the data to the costructor of my mapper , now I get this error return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xec in position 4: invalid continuation byte

Comment: @arpho `client_encoding` affects the data returned from the DB, as well as how the DB interprets data you send to it. So you must decode the data from the DB as `latin1` or `iso-8859-1` not as `utf-8`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, that your data, which can contain international characters, are Unicode strings. A string `'Forl\xec-Cesena'` which you try to insert, is in `Latin1` (`ISO-8859-1`) encoding. So use

```
unicode('Forl\xec-Cesena','Latin1')
```

to convert it to unicode string.